# Backreference to capturing group in vim

Tags: regex, vim, matching, backreference

In some text I need to find a string which may be one of the followning

```
foo#foo%foo
foo#foo%bar
foo#bar%foo
foo#bar%bar
bar#foo%foo
bar#foo%bar
bar#bar%foo
bar#bar%bar
```

I could write regex matcher like this

```
/\(foo\|bar\)#\(foo\|bar\)%\(foo\|bar\)
```

which works fine.

But I want to avoid duplication of capturing groups in the matcher.

If I write something like

```
/\(foo\|bar\)#\1%\1
```

it matches only FIRST and LAST possible strings I mentioned in the beginning.

Q: could I reference to previous capturing group itself, NOT previous match?

Comment: No, that's not how regexps work.

Comment: @lcd047: There are many regexp dialects. That is not how Vim regexps work. You can do that in Oniguruma (Ruby's regexp engine), for instance ([rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DR9vxPA3cv))

Comment: @Amadan You can also do it with [perl regexps](https://regex101.com/r/aD2cM0/1), and probably many others.  However, I believe the OP's question was about Vim.  Vim is mentioned in the title of the post, which makes it rather hard to miss.  Was there any particular reason to infer from my answer that I was referring to anything else than Vim regexps?

Comment: @lcd047: No. But there is also no particular reason to prevent inferring that you mean all regexp anywhere; which is not that big of a stretch since up to rather recently no regexp engine was able to do it, and in theoretical regular expressions it is simply a foreign concept. I was merely clarifying, for benefit of possible readers who might not know as much about regexps as you obviously do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely under wanting to create and reuse sub-patterns and reusing them like @Amadan and @lcd047 [alluded](http://rubular.com/r/DR9vxPA3cv) [to](https://regex101.com/r/aD2cM0/1) however Vim does not support this behavior that I am aware of.

As an alternative you can use `<c-f>` while editing your pattern to open up the `command-line-window`. Inside this window you can edit the pattern with your normal Vim commands, e.g. `daw`, `ct)`, etc. Once you are done you can press `<cr>` and run the search/command.

There is a nice [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode about this: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/).

For more help see:

```
:h command-line-window
:h q/
:h c_Ctrl-f
```

Comment: Yup, the command-line window is a tremendously useful feature, it should be mentioned more often.  On a side note, `q?` opens the same window for searching backwards, and `q:` opens a similar window for editing Ex commands.